# ruby-install to install latest ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-install

Right now the latest ruby my ruby-install will install is 2.3.0, but ruby 2.3.1 was released about 45 days ago.

Is there a step I need to do do have ruby-install have the ability install the latest?

Comment: You mean you want to update from ruby 2.3.0 to 2.3.1?

Comment: I want to install 2.3.1. I just thought using "2.3.1" in the title would be an obsolete issue in 1 month or 2, but the problem could persist with the "next" latest version. So I used "latest ruby"

Comment: What have you tried? The docs suggest `$ ruby-install --latest` or `$ ruby-install ruby 2.3.1`... what is the output of either of these commands?

Comment: I just ran it a couple days ago. It should be `ruby-install ruby-2.3.1`. Note the dash between the second ruby and the version.

Comment: @MattClark as of ruby-install 0.6.0, it will support `ruby-install [options...] RUBY-VERSION`. Historically, you'd want to use `ruby-install [options...] RUBY VERSION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your system meets the requirements & it is installed correctly, here are some useful commands that should help. 
(obviously do not include `$` as it is only to represent cmd prompt)

List supported Rubies and their major versions: `$ ruby-install`

List the latest versions: `$ ruby-install --latest`

Install the current stable version of Ruby: `$ ruby-install ruby`

Install the latest version of Ruby: `$ ruby-install --latest ruby`

Install a stable version of Ruby: `$ ruby-install ruby 2.3`

Install a specific version of Ruby: `$ ruby-install ruby 2.3.1`

Install a Ruby into a specific directory: `$ ruby-install --install-dir /path/to/dir ruby`

Here is a link to the documentation - https://git.io/vLJIJ

I would highly suggest a tool such as `rbenv` - which allows you to manage your ruby environment, downloading multiple versions & switch between them very easily +more - https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: Marking this correct for this command: ruby-install --latest, otherwise ruby-install didn't know about 2.3.1